# Use Enhanced For Loop Syntax is outputting slower result

Tags: java, android

I was reading the Google documents page when I came across this article http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Can anyone explain why I'm getting the opposite results?

My results are: (on average)
Result 1: 76
Result 2: 73
Result 3: 143

I performed some tests (looped over and over same tests) using the following code:

```
package TestPack;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test
{
static ArrayList<Integer> mTheArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        mTheArray.add(1234234223);
    }
}

static long mTimeStarted;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //Test 1.
    mTimeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
    One();
    Fn.Out("Result 1: " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - mTimeStarted));

    //Test 2.
    mTimeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Two();
    Fn.Out("Result 2: " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - mTimeStarted));

    //Test 3
    mTimeStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Three();
    Fn.Out("Result 3: " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - mTimeStarted));

}

//Slowest (But not...).
public static int One()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mTheArray.size(); ++i) 
    {
        sum += mTheArray.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int Two()
{
    int sum = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> localArray = mTheArray;
    int len = localArray.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += localArray.get(i);
    }
    return sum;
}

//Fastest (But actually slowest in this test).
public static int Three()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (Integer a : mTheArray) {
        sum += a;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page you linked specifically states that:

> With an ArrayList, a hand-written counted loop is about 3x faster
> (with or without JIT), but for other collections the enhanced for loop
> syntax will be exactly equivalent to explicit iterator usage.
>
> So, you should use the enhanced for loop by default, but consider a hand-written counted loop for performance-critical `ArrayList` iteration.

You're using an ArrayList, so the results you're getting seem fairly consistent with this statement.